# Ask for help to identifying unknown seeds

Tags: food-identification, seeds

My family member have left these seeds behind.
I am not sure what is it, any one could help in identifying?
I have compared to Sesame, Chia. These seeds seed have no smell and completely black if using magnifying glass to see. Chia have some white and cracks alike while sesame have its special smell. So I am not sure what it is.

Edited on 2024/3/24
I have tried taking another shot by wearing a white glove with a spotlight on the palm. It seems to look much better.
I have taken two shots, one with a large quantity of the same type of seeds grouped together to compare sizes, and another with fewer seeds. Providing both images from different perspectives for a better understanding of the seeds' morphology.

[image: unknown seed]

[image: unknown seed with spotlight large quantity]

[image: unknown seed with spotlight fewer quantity]

Comment: How big are the seeds - the photo makes them look about the size of beans, but I suspect that they are more on the size of chia and sesame as you mention those in comments. Also - where are you in the world (Hong Kong from profile)? What seeds might be available depend heavily on where you are.

Comment: The photo is very close up, and blurry.  Folks are going to need better photos to identify.  Also, are you certain that they are *edible* seeds?

Comment: @bob1 it is about the size of a sesame, I am residing in Hong Kong. As far as I can remember, the most common black seed is sesame, chia. While other kind of seeds are also available such as Flax seed which is small but in brown color and in case for long storage, the bad oil smell come out due to oxidation which I have experienced before.

Comment: @FuzzyChef It is being put into Kitchen shelf. Since food are usually grouped together so I am quite certain that it is editable. It is somewhat hard to take clear photo, I use iPhone and magnifying glass to take the photo. Do you have better suggestion or technique which I could try?

Comment: Could be Kalonji/Nigella/Black Cumin - What does it taste like? Probably not Black Sesame as those look like White Sesame, only dark coloured. Have your family been making any Indian style dishes (curry or naan/roti?)

Comment: Don't use a magnifying glass, that won't work.  Give us one picture on maximum zoom (but still clear), and maybe another one with the seeds next to your finger so that we can see size.

Comment: @bob1 the shape looks kind of triangular, which would also indicate nigella.

Comment: @Esther Is nigella also known as Black Cumin?

Comment: @西門正CodeGuy yes, it is

Comment: It is sometimes, but so is Elwendia.  Though, these definitely aren't elwendia seeds.

Comment: @FuzzyChef
I have tried another kind of technique and setup to take the photo. It seems much better now. Hopefully, this could help in identifying the seed.

Comment: I've found a stock photo of what are supposedly Chia seeds. They look closer to what's in your photos than Sesame, Nigella, or the various seeds that are all known as "black cumin". The surfaces is smooth and shiny, unlike pretty much everything other than Sesame seeds. The shapes vary with some seeds showing a similar flattened, pinched end as your seeds do. 

https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/z/healthy-black-chia-seeds-healthy-black-chia-seeds-benefits-chia-seeds-179483492.jpg

Perhaps I've missed something but... why not just ask your family what they are?

Comment: My family member who left this jar of seeds has already passed away...

Comment: My condolences. One thing that might help to identify mystery seeds is if you were to crack open or crush a few. Seeing what colour the interior is could help to narrow down the list of possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to be absolutely certain, but with the new photos those appear to be [black sesame seeds](https://www.spiceography.com/black-sesame-seeds-vs-white/). They don't look like nigella seeds, since they lack the ridges those seeds have.

Taste them; if they taste slightly bitter with a sesame flavor, that's what you have.